# Checking XML node values in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm iterating through a VERY large REST api response in XML format. Every time I see a node called `<TaxiCode>`, for example, I want to save it's value to a variable (below I just print it out). The code below is just a snippet and does iterate through each node.

```
 def doc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlResponse)
 doc.Itinerary.each { Itinerary ->
 Itinerary.children().each { tag ->
      if (${tag.name()} == "TaxiCode") {
                println "${tag.name()}: ${tag.text()}"
      }

 ...
```

I'm not sure how to format the if statement, very new to Groovy and I can't find any similar code.

I don't want to do an assert!
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I answered my own question. I just had to remove the ${} from the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do in one-liner:

```
println doc.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'TaxiCode'}*.text()
```